# Trying to Insert Multiplied Values into a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a table where the values show up as a multiplied value from a two separate tables. In total, there are five tables being used. I've created two queries that give me an output that I want which are

```
SELECT Name = Person_Exercise.Name, Minutes_Exercised * Calories_Burned_Per_Minute AS 'Calories Burned', Date
FROM Person_Exercise
    JOIN Exercise ON Exercise.Exercise = Person_Exercise.Exercise
```

and

```
SELECT Person, SUM(Servings * Calories_Per_Unit) AS 'Total Calories', Date
FROM Person_Food
    JOIN Food ON Food.Name = Person_Food.Food
GROUP BY Person_Food.Person, Date
```

However, when I try to put all the together, the correct "total calories" is way off and adds up to a rather large number. I know something in this is wrong but I'm not sure what.

```
INSERT INTO Person_Calorie_Interaction (Name, Calories_Consumed,Calories_Burned, Net_Calories, Date)
SELECT Name = Person.Name, SUM(Servings * Calories_Per_Unit), SUM(Minutes_Exercised + Calories_Burned_Per_Minute), SUM(Servings * Calories_Per_Unit - Minutes_Exercised * Calories_Burned_Per_Minute), Date = Date.Date
FROM Person
    JOIN Person_Food ON Person_Food.Person = Person.Name
    JOIN Date ON Person_Food.Date = Date.Date
    JOIN Food ON Food.Name = Person_Food.Food
    JOIN Person_Exercise ON Person_Exercise.Name = Person.Name
    JOIN Exercise ON Exercise.Exercise = Person_Exercise.Exercise
GROUP BY Person.Name, Date.Date
```

Comment: Is it mysql or SQL Server? Please don't overtag.

Comment: There is no table named `Date` in your initial queries but there is in the INSERT version. Same for `Person`.

Comment: Using SUM will work with your GROUP BY statement and add across multiple lines. Also, is there a problem with your parenthesis within the select statement? ...so it should be SELECT Name = Person.Name, SUM(Servings * Calories_Per_Unit), SUM(Minutes_Exercised + Calories_Burned_Per_Minute), SUM((Servings * Calories_Per_Unit) - (Minutes_Exercised * Calories_Burned_Per_Minute)), Date = Date.Date

Comment: The problem I'm having is that the Join Statements are causing the results in "Calories Consumed" and "Calories_Burned" to quadruple.